# custom label in class

Tags: apex

How to create one single custom label for below complete statement. Is there any feasibility ? Please let me know. Thanks in advance..

```
Case.Status= \'New\'  or Case.Status = \'Working\' or (Case.Status = \'Escalated\')
```

Answer (score 1):

Create `Set` of desired statuses and then use [variable binding](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm)

if you want to have dynamic control of what statuses should be selected without changes to apex code, you can create [Custom Metadata Types](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_overview.htm&type=0&language=en_US) add text field `CaseStatuses__c` api name here, split Case statuses with delimiter (; for example).
Create new instance of custom metadata types with name `CaseFields` and values for `CaseStatuses__c = 'New;Working;Escalated'`

Then do the following in code:

```
CustomMetadata_mdt mdt = [
    select CaseStatuses__c
    from CustomMetadata_mdt
    where DeveloperName = 'CaseFields'
    limit 1
    ];

Set<String> caseStatuses = new Set<String>(
    mdt.CaseStatuses__c.split(';')
    );
[
... 
where Case.Status in :caseStatuses
];
```

Comment: hi Alex, can we iunclude custom picklist  fields along with values in custom labels

Comment: @sohel  do you want to have these Statuses easy configurable by admin, without changes in code ?

Comment: yes alex. I can use custom label for single value like "new", or "Working" and will refer these values as $Label.CustomLabel. But I want to use custom label for multiple values Case.Status= \'New\'  or Case.Status = \'Working\'

Comment: @sohel I've updated my answer with better solution for it: by means  of custom metadata types

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. Anyhow thanks for your time.

Comment: @sohel can you provide example of what do you want?